# Changing Server state: am I doing it right?

Tags: java, multithreading, future

I'm implementing the [Raft Consensus Algorithm](https://raftconsensus.github.io/) for a Distributed System project. In few words, there are three states:

1. Follower
2. Candidate
3. Leader

I will not tell you the specifics of each state, but a Follower could become a Candidate and a Candidate could become a Leader. In addiction, someone outside could make become a Candidate or a Leader a Follower again. During each one of these states, a Server will perform different tasks.

So I started thinking how to implement this "state changing" aspect, and this is the result:

```
public abstract class ServerState implements Runnable {
    protected Random timeoutGenerator;
    public ServerState()
    {
        timeoutGenerator = new Random();
    }
    @Override
    public abstract void run();
    public abstract ServerState timeout();
    public abstract ServerState taskCompleted() throws UnexpectedStateException;
    public abstract long generateTimeout();
}

public class Follower extends ServerState{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello world! I'm a follower!");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    @Override
    public ServerState timeout() {
        return new Candidate();
    }

    @Override
    public ServerState taskCompleted() throws UnexpectedStateException{
        throw new UnexpectedStateException();
    }

    @Override
    public long generateTimeout() {
        return timeoutGenerator.nextInt(490)+10;
    }
}
```

**I will not post the code relative to Candidate and Leader, since they are very similar to follower. The most interesting part is the Executor class:**

```
public class Executor extends Thread{
    ExecutorService executor;
    Future<?> future;
    ServerState state;

    public Executor ()
    {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        state = new Follower();
    }

    public synchronized void changeState(ServerState newState)
    {
        future.cancel(true);
        executor.shutdownNow();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        state = newState;
        future = executor.submit(state);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        future = executor.submit(state);
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                future.get(state.generateTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);//each server state has a different timeout
                changeState(state.taskCompleted());
            }
            catch (CancellationException e){
                System.out.println("Cancelled!");
            }
            catch (UnexpectedStateException |  InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                executor.shutdownNow();
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
             catch (TimeoutException e) {
                System.out.println("Timeout! Changing state");
                changeState(state.timeout());//state.timeout return the new ServerState when the timeout elapse
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I already said, someone else could change the actual State of the Server switching it to a Follower (calling in fact `changeState(new Follower())`).

Now, I ask you some questions:

1. Do you have any better idea to improve the quality (code readability) of this code?
2. Do you think that's it is thread safe? I implemented this solution in order that if the state of the Server is changed is made inside the `changeState` method, which is `synchronized` and so it should be thread safe, but I'd like an opinion from you anyway!
3. There is an aspect that I don't understand: this is the log of an execution:

   Hello world! I'm a follower!
   Timeout! Changing state
   Hello world! I'm a Candidate!
   Timeout! Changing state
   Hello world! I'm a Candidate!
   Timeout! Changing state
   Hello world! I'm a Candidate!
   Timeout! Changing state
   Hello world! I'm a Candidate!
   **EXTERNAL CHANGE!
   Cancelled!
   Cancelled!
   Cancelled!
   Cancelled!
   Cancelled!
   Cancelled!
   Hello world! I'm a follower!
   And so on and so forth...**

(sorry for the layout, I don't know why Stack Overflow write it in only one line)

Why the messages `Cancelled!` appear only where there is an `EXTERNAL CHANGE` event? Anytime that `changeState()` is called the instruction `future.cancel(true)` and so every time that it is executed a `CancellationException` should have been raisead!

What is actually happening? I'm afraid that there is something that I don't understand about future...

Comment: This might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Question 1 and 2 is better for Code Review, but Code Review *is not about helping you understand the code you have*.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. However since there is something that I cannot explain from my own code, I posted it here in order to find an answer from this splendid community which helped me so many times. I apologize if I did it wrong.